# MudBlazor/Blazor (Server): Full Screen App

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Is it possible to create a "Full Screen(Browser Window) Website" with MudBlazor (in Blazor Server)?

What I want is, that the **@Body** part fills the complete rest of the browser window. So it's not really a full screen/browser div, but a div that fills the complete **body** and does not resize when it hosts a larger child element. When you look at the layout below, you'll see that there is an AppBar and a MudDrawer(Sidebar). So these need to be deducted from a full screen size div. And since the Sidebar can show/hide, the 'filling' div needs to adapt to the remaining space.

Any idea, how to solve this problem?

```
<MudLayout>
<MudAppBar Elevation="1">
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
</MudAppBar>
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always">
    <MudNavMenu>
    <MudNavLink Href="/">Home</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavMenu>
</MudDrawer>
<MudMainContent>
    @Body
</MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

Comment: I don't yet get exactly what you need. Here is a fiddle with your code. Can you post a screenshot what it should look like? 
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYcvPbbqhQCOBrWX